# SQL - Updating multiple records for each record with a matching id in a table

Tags: sql-server

I am bit new on the updating multiple records and i wanted to know the best way to go on about a solution for this, i am writing a stored proc were basically i have two tables, 
one that matches a server id to a user id
and another table with record information for each user id with multiple columns with values.

Basically here is how its going to work:

Get all the matching user ids for the specific server id in the tb_UserServerMap table
then foreach userId in the tb_setting table update the columns with the new values

Comment: You can help get a better answer if you include your table schemas and an expected outcome of what you're trying to achieve (before/after). Have a look at some of the higher voted related questions for what I mean

Answer (score 1):

Basic structure of your stored procedure would be:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Blah
    @Server_ID int /* or whatever data type is appropriate */
as
    UPDATE ts
    SET
        ColumnA = 10 /* New value for column A - maybe passed as a parameter? */
        /* More columns here */
    FROM
        tb_setting ts
            inner join
        tb_UserServerMap usm
            on
                ts.user_id = usm.user_id
    WHERE
        usm.server_id = @Server_ID
```

I can't fill in more of it without knowing the names of columns to be updated, how those values are obtained, data types, etc.

Comment: +1. I'm sure this template delivers the basic idea well and is good to get started with.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a foreach,

Update tblName set firstCol = val1, secondCol = val2 where id in (id1, id2, id3)